# Process tab delimited file and save each column as variable

Tags: shell, unix

I have a tab delimited `feadList` that has two columns (`date` + `id`):

```
20130509    1319
20130510    1320
20130511    1321
20130512    1322
20130513    1323
```

While reading each line, I want to curl data from a web link using `id` then save into a file with `date` as the file name. For now I have something like:

```
for feed in $feadList
do
    awk -F "\t" '{print date=$1, seq=$2}' $feed
    curl "$WebLink/$seq/data" > $date
done
```

but apparently it doesn't work. Guys shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different way to do it would be

```sh
while read date seq
do
    curl "$WebLink/$seq/data" > $date
done < feadList
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while read date seq
do
    curl "$WebLink/$seq/data" > $date
done < feadList
```

The `read` command (a shell built-in) splits the data lines into two fields assigned to `$date` and `$seq`, and then you can use these in the body of the loop.  If there were extra fields on a line, they'd be recorded in `$seq` too.

Your shell notations are simply not going to work as you need.  The loop would be executed exactly once with the value in the variable `$feadList` (which is distinct from `feadList` as a file name).  The `awk` command would output to standard output one line for each input line, containing the split data.  But that would be simple output...there'd be no assignment to the shell variables `$date` and `$seq`, and the `curl` command would not work as expected.